# Facing issue when running npm run build

Tags: npm, webpack, angular17

I am facing the following error when running `npm run build` in angular project:

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i31.DragAndDropModule to symbol

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i31.DragAndDropModule to symbol
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

I have tried a lot many ways to solve this issue, but didn't find any resolution.